# Killed a dragon with Whirlwind Sprint?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So long story short I got attacked by a dragon and it landed directly in front of me.  I went to use "Unrelenting Force" to stun it, but forgot that I actually had "Whirlwind Sprint" (fully upgraded) equipped.  So my character sprinted straight through the dragon, and when I turned around to go back to the fight I saw the dragon keeling over, dead.  I did not land a single attack on the dragon.

I tried to repeat this intentionally with a second dragon, but it didn't seem to work (my character seemed to get forced off to the side instead of going straight through the dragon).

So I'm wondering, has anyone else killed a dragon using Whirlwind Sprint?  Is this an intentional gameplay element, or a bug, or did some other random thing that has nothing to do with my shout kill the first dragon?

Comment: Did you have a follower, were you using an axe, or did you set the dragon on fire?

Comment: I did have a follower (the dark-elf mage from the college), but they're definitely not strong enough to kill a dragon that quickly (or at all) without help.  The dragon was not set on fire.  The weapon I had at the time was a daedric greatsword, but I never hit the dragon with it.

Comment: You killed the dragon from full health?

Comment: Did you come across the dragon while it was fighting other npc's like town guards or giants? If you don't land any damage you don't get the soul.

Comment: Yes, killed it from full health.  And I did not get a soul from it.  I was a bit confused about that as well.  There were no NPC's or other critters around.

Comment: Sounds like a bug - unless you toppled the poor dragon over a cliff when smashing into him?

Comment: Damage over time effect?

Comment: Keep in mind that some dragons follow paths and encounter hostiles. Its possible for a dragon to be badly wounded by, say, a Giant before you come along.

Comment: There's only one explanation : http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SingleStrokeBattle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have triggered a glitch or bug, which may have seen you moving through the dragon as an attack, and not a movement technique. 
If you can't preform it more than once, it was most likely just a hiccup in the game. A damn good one, if I may add. :3

Comment: I did the same thing with a draugr death overlord! He stood on a trap which hit him and took about a 10th of his health, and as the trap was resetting I whirlwind sprinted him to death! I know by the timing of his death sound that it was the sprint that killed him. I figure the game considered him still in "trap collision damage on" mode and my sprint was considered a heavy collision, and thus, heavy damage.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but I experienced something similar on a few occassions.

It is possible that a dragon actually crash lands (taking heavy damage) and dies, which might have been the cause. In my experience there are two ways this can happen:

- Dragon Rend enforces the dragon to land, if there is little space to land, it can take time for the dragon to find a spot and may actually be too late. Long story short, the dragon is forced to the ground (and takes heavy damage) and if you are in a snowy area, it will leave a sliding trail.
- The dragon tried to land (potentially after taking damage) but 'glitches' into a tree/rock/bush, this may trigger the dragon crashing into the ground, but you will see little of this because it is already close to the ground. However, it may still die!

The second option would seem viable and would also explain why you would be able to sprint through it (imagine a very small spot between the dragon and the ground that you passed through). Not receiving the dragon soul might be explained by not having attacked it, but the dragon dying none the less.